# Error "Unable to find type [Amazon.AWSClientFactory]" in Powershell trying to log into AWS S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, powershell, amazon-s3

I need to upload files from a PC to an S3 bucket using a Powershell script.
I get error: "Unable to find type [Amazon.AWSClientFactory]" trying to attach to AWS S3. I installed the AWS Powershell stuff. I am in the blue AWS Powershell window.

$client=[Amazon.AWSClientFactory]::CreateAmazonS3Client($accessKeyID,$secretAccessKey,$config)

Comment: Initialize-AWSDefaults -Region $RegionEndpoint -AccessKey $accessKeyID -SecretKey $secretAccessKey

Answer (score 0):

Found an answer from a previous post here.
Replaced line:
$client=[Amazon.AWSClientFactory]::CreateAmazonS3Client($accessKeyID,$secretAccessKey,$config)

With:
Initialize-AWSDefaults -Region $RegionEndpoint -AccessKey $accessKeyID -SecretKey $secretAccessKey